# Symfony Process - Command not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-process

I'm trying to execute ffmpeg commands using Symfony Process Component but command is not being processed. What am I doing wrong?
I get the error

> The command "'ffmpeg -i [...........]' failed. Exit Code: 127(Command
> not found)"

```
<?php 
$info = pathinfo($file);
$dir = "{$info['dirname']}/{$info['filename']}";
File::makeDirectory($dir, 0755, true)
$process = new Process(["ffmpeg -i {$info['basename']} -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list {$dir}/playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 {$dir}/{$info['filename']}_%02d.ts"]);
$process->setWorkingDirectory($info['dirname']);
$process->start();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
echo $process->getOutput();
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put each argument in a separate element of the array, for example:

```
$process = new Process([
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    "{$info['basename']}",
    "-codec",
    "copy",
    "-map",
    "0",
    "-f",
    "segment",
    "-segment_list",
    "{$dir}/playlist.m3u8",
    "-segment_list_flags",
    "+live",
    "-segment_time",
    "10",
    "{$dir}/{$info['filename']}_%02d.ts",
]);
```

And I think you should either:

- use `$process->run()` instead of `$process->start()`
- or read in more detail [how to run a process asynchronously](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously) with `$process->start()`